# Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

there is a problem in identity mvc 5 :
when a user want to view my controlers i use [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] to login just admin roles.
so when user redirected to login page and do login this error will show :

```
Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.         Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

Source Error: 


Line 73:             // This doen't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
Line 74:             // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
Line 75:             var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
Line 76:             switch (result)
Line 77:             {
```

my user is an admin but i dont know any thing about this error, It is noteworthy that i am using the Asp.Net identity sample via nuget.

Answer (score 1):

I solved My Question by Delete Tables of Identity From my database and rebuild project and run again and create new user to create tables again, so that the problem has been solved!